# Are closures thread safe?

Tags: swift, multithreading, thread-safety

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
class Bla {
    var callback: (() -> Void)?

    // doStuff will be called from multiple threads
    func doStuff() {
        callback?()
    }
}
```

Is it thread safe to call a closure from multiple threads? The closure will not be modified during this time, only called.

Inside the closure is thread safe code.

Comment: I don't have a source for this, but yes, it's safe. So long as the body of the closure doesn't itself do something that isn't thread safe, obviously

Comment: I would post that as an answer, but it would be misleading if I could substantiate a source. Hopefully somebody else could chime in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately thread safety isn't a straight forward question. Specifically though the read of the block is safe from multiple threads.

In swift closures are passed by reference. When you assign it to "var callback" it receives a memory address in the heap. That address can be read by multiple threads at once as long as the variable is not changing at the time of read access by some other thread. Even if you captured a variable in the block, that variable would be captured by the block and if it wasn't a reference type could even be modified by the closure. You definitely want to be careful what you do inside the calling site though. If for instance the closure is called by multiple threads and inside you passed say..

```
var i = 0 
callback = {
     i += 1
}


for _ in 0...100 {
      
     DispatchQueue.global().async {
            bla.closure()
    }
 }
```

This would obviously no long be considered "thread safe" because you are still mutating by multiple threads. For example two or three threads may read 1 and add 1, another twelve threads may read 5 and write 6 on return; or worse the second thread finished last and after 100 calls you have i = 2.

Additionally, if "var i" were a reference type the program would likely crash on a bad access exception.

Comment: It would be better to say that the closure itself is thread-safe, but if the closure mutates any reference types, it is no more or less thread-safe than any other concurrent code that tries to mutate shared memory. (You did say that if I read your entire answer, but somebody skimming your answer might get the wrong idea.)

Comment: @DuncanC thanks for the input, I'll move that to the top of the answer.